# ElasticSearch: preserve_position_increments not working

Tags: elasticsearch, lucene

According to the docs

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-suggesters-completion.html

preserve_position_increments=false is supposed to make consecutive keywords in a string searchable. But for me it's not working. Is this a bug? Steps to reproduce in Kibana:

```
PUT /example-index/
{
  "settings": {
    "number_of_shards": 1,
    "number_of_replicas": 0
  },
  "mappings": {
    "_doc": {
      "properties": {
        "example-suggest-field": {
          "type": "completion",
          "analyzer": "stop",
          "preserve_position_increments": false,
          "max_input_length": 50
        }
      }
    }
  }
}

PUT /example-index/_doc/1
{
  "example-suggest-field": [
        {
            "input": "Nevermind Nirvana",
            "weight" : 10
        }
    ]
}

POST /example-index/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "bib-suggest" : {
        "prefix" : "nir",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "example-suggest-field"
        }
    }
  }
}

POST /example-index/_search
{
  "suggest": {
    "bib-suggest" : {
        "prefix" : "nev",
        "completion" : {
            "field" : "example-suggest-field"
        }
    }
  }
}
```

If yes I will make a bug report

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It's not a bug, `preserve_position_increments` is only useful when you are removing stopwords and would like to search for the token coming after the stopword (i.e. search for `Beat` and find `The Beatles`).

In your case, you should probably index `["Nevermind", "Nirvana"]` instead, i.e. and array of tokens.

If you try to indexing `"The Nirvana"` instead, you'll find it by searching for `nir`

Comment: ok this makes things clear. I thought stopwords are all the elements used in the  tokenizer, not language-specific terms. thank you.